# How to extract digits from String (e.g. a phone number) in Dart/Flutter?

Tags: string, flutter, dart

I've got several types of phone numbers as a String:

For example:

```
+49 176 666 454 414

+49(176)-666454414

+49176-666454414
```

But I would like to convert every type of phone number like the following :
`+4917622265414`

Basically only digits.

How can I do that in dart? Aynone has an idea?
I could do like below but I'm sure there must be a better way to do that.

```
String result = gfg.replaceAll(" ", "");

String result = gfg.replaceAll("(", "");

String result = gfg.replaceAll(")", "");

String result = gfg.replaceAll("-", "");
```

Thanks :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use regex to extract all digit from the string

```
String result = gfg.replaceAll(new RegExp(r'[^0-9]'),'');
```

And add the **+** at the begining

```
result = "+$result";
```

Does it help you ?

Comment: Thanks @Abdel

That's what I was looking for :)